# SetWindowPos for a specific window

Tags: c#, windows, move

I have

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(string hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
```

My issue is I want to be able to move a specific window based on the text inside of my label.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const short SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
        const short SWP_NOZORDER = 0X4;
        const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();


        foreach (var process in processes)
        {
            IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
            string Text = handle.ToString();

            if (handle.ToString() == WindowTextBox.Text)
            {
                SetWindowPos(Text, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            }
        }
    }
```

I knew this wouldn't work but wanted to try anyway, how else would I be able to move a window based on what is inside my WindowTextBox? (having IntPtr handle in the SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, [...]) and just changing

```
SetWindowPos(Text, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

to

```
SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

doesn't work either.) Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the SetWindowPos is executing?

Comment: Yes I am, when I have it check if the handle is empty and just move all windows that are active, it works fine.

Comment: So `handle.ToString()` is not what you think.  You should trace it and WindowTextBox.Text.

Comment: Start by fixing the pinvoke declaration.  It's wrong, both the 1st and 2nd arguments are IntPtr.  Visit pinvoke.net for the right one: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowPos.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I used

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

to change the line to

```
IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, WindowTextBox.Text);
```

and the if to

```
if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
```

and it works just the way I want, thanks though!