# Print PDF hidden from user

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I have a PDF printed from C# with this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Verb = "printto";
info.FileName = segnToPrint;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.Arguments = "\""+ stmp+ "\"";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.WaitForInputIdle();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

// Close Acrobat regardless of version
if (p != null)
{
    p.WaitForInputIdle();
    p.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

stmp is the address of the printer. The print works fine and it's perfect but i see the windows of Acrobat Reader any time that i call this function and the page of Acrobat Reader remains open after the last file printed.

How can i hidden all the process to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (as you have found) acrobat reader will always open a window. If you wish to silently print without ever seeing acrobat then the only approach would be to use something other than acrobat reader. Two possible options are to use another PDF reader like [FoxIt](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) or to try to send your PDF directly to the printer in [raw form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091), getting round the need for 3rd party applications all-together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to hide some window then you may try move its window left and top position outside the screen using [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) function (see C# code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340373/setwindowpos-for-a-specific-window)).

But please be aware of user interactions as user could be confused by the program running in the taskbar but not available on desktop.